# A good (offline) HTML 5 + JS application for iPhone

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for good examples of applications written entirely in HTML5 and JS that are able to run on iPhone as regular apps.

I've heard that the HTML5+JS is an alternative to Objective-C but I haven't seen a really good application yet.

Comment: This is an excellent question. My experience has shown it is not possible to create an offline web app on iPad/iPhone. Open the app today (online) and if you open the same link in a few days offline it won't work. Someone tell me i'm wrong in this day ang age!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Glyphboard is a clever example. The app is here: http://mrgan.com/gb/ (iPhone link) and some (technical) background info is here: http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/98547533/fullscreen-web-apps

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) framework site and view their examples. They have a really nice solitaire game or the iPad, but their apps are designed to run with a native look and feel on iPhone/iPad and Android, including offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

[Ibis Reader](http://ibisreader.com/).

Answer (score -1):

[speedof.me](http://speedof.me)

It's kind of speed test web app which can be run on iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

[TimeTracker](http://www.creativeworx.com/) by CreativeWorx should be a good example.